# determining a residue by taking a limit

Tags: complex-analysis, limits, residue-calculus

To determine a residue, I need to take this limit:
$$\lim_{z\to 2\pi ik} \frac{d}{dz}\frac{(z-2\pi ik)^2}{z(e^z-1)^2}$$
with $k$ any integer number (like -1, -1, 0, 3, 7)
I have tried l'Hopital's rule to take the limit but it gets a mess real quickly.
Is there an easy way to take this limit?

Comment: Are you trying to find the residue of $\;\frac1{z(z^z-1)^2}\;$ at $\;z=2\pi ik\;$ ?

Comment: I am trying to find the residue of 1/(z(exp(z)-1)^2) at z=2pi*i*k

Comment: In the last part of [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/804551/finding-the-poles-and-residues-of-a-complex-function-frac-cosz-1ez-1/804627#804627) answer, I do almost that.

Comment: Do you realize that the multiplicity of the pole is 3 if $k=0$?

Comment: yes I do, that is a separate part of my answer

Answer (score 1):

Start taking $w=z-2\pi ik$. Then,
$$
\begin{align}
\lim_{z\to 2\pi ik}\frac{d}{dz}\frac{(z-2\pi ik)^2}{z(e^z-1)^2} & =
\lim_{w\to 0}\frac{d}{dw}\frac{w^2}{(w+2\pi ik)(e^{(w+2\pi ik)}-1)^2}\\
& = \lim_{w\to 0}\frac{d}{dw}\frac{w^2}{(w+2\pi ik)(e^w-1)^2}\\
& = \lim_{w\to 0}\left(\frac{d}{dw}\frac1{(w+2\pi ik)}\right)\frac{w^2}{(e^w-1)^2}+
\lim_{w\to 0}\frac1{(w+2\pi ik)}\frac{d}{dw}\frac{w^2}{(e^w-1)^2}\\
& = -\frac1{(2k\pi i)^2}\cdot 1 +
\frac1{2k\pi i}\cdot\lim_{w\to 0}{{-2\,w\,\left(w\,e^{w}-e^{w}+1\right)}\over{\left(e^{w}-1\right)^3
 }}\\
& = \frac1{4k^2\pi^2}+
\frac{i}{2k\pi}\lim_{w\to 0}\frac{w^3+\cdots}{w^3+\cdots}=\frac1{4k^2\pi^2}+
\frac{i}{2k\pi}
\end{align}
$$

Alternate solution: find the first (negative) terms of the Laurent series like in [First four terms of the power series of $f(z) = \frac{z}{e^z-1}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/966478/first-four-terms-of-the-power-series-of-fz-fraczez-1/966497#966497). The residue is by definition the coefficient of the $(-1)$-th term.

Comment: I still can't seem to figure it out, because whatever I do, I am always stuck with a ((e^z)-1)^2 in the denominator. Can you give me another hint?

Comment: @Boe, the exponential is periodic, the series of the exponential is...

Comment: I know how to expand ((e^z)-1)^2, but in the limit I'm always dividing by zero, because the power of the terms in the denominator are always higher then the power of the terms in numerator.

Comment: @Boe, the calculations are really hideous. I will try to find a human-readable solution.

Comment: I would appreciate that, thank you

Comment: @Boe, check my calculations.

Comment: Thank you!!! You're awesome